# arc welder no internet connection through proxy

Tags: android, google-chrome, google-chrome-arc

I used arc welder (https://developer.chrome.com/apps/getstarted_arc) to make an Chrome app out of an Android app, and everything is fine until I try to get an Internet connection behind proxy in the Chrome app. 
It connects to the Internet fine, when there's no proxy. But I can't find any proxy settings to fill in, and apparently it doesn't use Chrome's settings for this (I use Chrome behind a proxy with no problems).
Is it possible to get Internet connection in an arc welder app behind proxy??
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, there is not a way currently for ARC apps to use the Chrome proxy settings.

Feel free to star/follow the existing bug for it: http://crbug.com/416557

Comment: Hmmm, too bad cause the idea of having apps from android in chrome is brilliant. I starred it. Thanks!